# Using Node.Js Globals in WebStorm 2016

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I recently upgraded to WebStorm 2016 from WebStorm 9 for debugging my NodeJS projects. But I cannot seem to find any option to enable NodeJS Globals like in WebStorm 9 (I can only enable NodeJS Core).

How can I enable NodeJS Globals and NodeJS Core in WebStorm 2016?

Comment: AFAIK it's the same (it's just got renamed)... https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/11/node-js-coding-assistance-in-webstorm-11/

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still getting an "unresolved method or function" for common methods like res.render('index')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) is an Express framework method, it's not a part of Node.js core. You need to download the Typescript community stubs for express, express-serve-static-core and serve-static modules to get Express methods resolved: `Settings | languages & Frameworks | javaScript | Libraries`, press Download..., choose needed modules from the list

Comment: Thanks! Seemed to have worked. But why are we doing this manually now?

Comment: this have never worked out of the box. WebStorm is unable to resolve Express methods from node_modules due to a tricky way they are defined - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6667#comment=27-470393.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like same problem I had (things like require() and exit() wouldn't resolve). Found this on the jetbrains support page and it worked for me:

"'Node.js Globals' library has been merged with 'Node.js Core Modules', and can be enabled in Settings/Languages & Frameworks/Node.js and NPM"
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999855-Node-js-Globals-library-missing-from-10-0-1-?sort_by=votes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...

PS: You don't need to download the javascript libraries.